# Match Coordinate Array in MongoDB Query

Tags: mongodb, waterline

I have latitude and longitude array but I can not match with whole array. So I have to iterate loop and execute following single query in loop. so It will take to much time for execute query.

**My Following Query in Loop**

```
Collection.find({'location':{$near:{$geometry:{type:"point",coordinates:[longitude,latitude]},$maxDistance:20}}}).exec(function(err,res){
});
```

**Expect Query Like**

```
{'location':{$near:{$geometry:{type:"point",coordinates:[[longitude,latitude],[longitude,latitude],[longitude,latitude]]},$maxDistance:20}}}
```

I have coordinates array but I can not pass whole array here so I have to pass single latitude and longitude in loop.

Is there any way to find data from database using coordinate Array?

**Update**

I tried following Query

```
Collection.find({'location':{$near:{$geometry:{type:"point",coordinates:[[72.502912,23.011787],[ 72.50265, 23.011772 ]]},$maxDistance:20}}});
```

**I got following error**

```
error: {
    "waitedMS" : NumberLong(0),
    "ok" : 0,
    "errmsg" : "invalid point in geo near query $geometry argument: { type: \"point\", coordinates: [ [ 72.50291199999999, 23.011787 ], [ 72.50265, 23.011772 ] ] }  Point must only contain numeric elements",
    "code" : 2
}
```

**Document**

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5abcf7ae59869428b40c5727"),
    "latitude" : 23.8787,
    "longitude" : 72.7788,
    "location" : [
        72.7788,
        23.8787
    ],
    "address" : "Ahmedabad",
    "status" : "active",
    "eventId" : "5a8d6a27733b28295db9635e",
    "eventCreateBy" : "admin",
    "description" : "",
    "isDeleted" : "0",
    "createdAt" : ISODate("2018-03-29T14:26:54.198Z"),
    "updatedAt" : ISODate("2018-03-29T14:26:54.198Z")
}
```

**Coordinates**

```
[72.7788,23.8787] : Matched
[72.5032552,23.0122194]: Matched
[18.1519461,43.8984328]: Not Matched
```

Comment: If anyone unclear what I am asking please comment here. I will explain what I want.

Comment: Yes, please explain why you cannot use array.

Comment: I Got error when I use `coordinates:[[longitude,latitude],[longitude,latitude],[longitude,latitude]]`

Comment: Ah, fair enough. It's wrong syntax. It should be an array of `{$near:{...}}` conditions wrapped in `$and`, `$or`, or combination of both, depending on what you expect - intersection or union of the matching documents.

Comment: Can you give me overview of query. How I can achieve my goal

Comment: Sure, please update the question with examples of the array (at least 2 pairs of coordinates) and the documents (at least 3: 2 to match each pair of the coordinates, and 1 that doesn't match any) so I could answer it.

Comment: @AlexBlex Check my edited question I putted my document and coordinates

Answer (score 0):

**The problem**

It is not going to work with [$near](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/near/). The function sorts results by distance, and it is not clear in which order to return results when there are more than 1 `$near` operator in the query, so requests like

```
db.collection.find({$or: [
    {'location':{$near:{$geometry:{type:"point",coordinates:[ 72.50325, 23.01222 ]},$maxDistance:50000}}},
    {'location':{$near:{$geometry:{type:"point",coordinates:[ 72.7788, 23.8787 ]},$maxDistance:50000}}}
]});
```

are explicitly forbidden in https://github.com/mongodb/mongo/blob/3cbb3eb/src/mongo/db/query/canonical_query.cpp#L346 :

```
// There can only be one NEAR.  If there is a NEAR, it must be either the root or the root
// must be an AND and its child must be a NEAR.
size_t numGeoNear = countNodes(root, MatchExpression::GEO_NEAR);
if (numGeoNear > 1) {
    return Status(ErrorCodes::BadValue, "Too many geoNear expressions");
}
```

---

**The workaround**

Is to use [$geoWithin](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/geoWithin/).

To return all documents within 50km radius around **any** of coordinates (union):

```
db.collection.find(
    {$or: [
        {'location':{$geoWithin: {$centerSphere:[[ 72.50325, 23.01222 ], 50 / 6378.1]}}},
        {'location':{$geoWithin: {$centerSphere:[[ 72.7788, 23.8787 ], 50 / 6378.1]}}}
    ]}
)
```

returns both documents.

To return all documents within 50km radius around **all** of coordinates (intersection):

```
db.collection.find(
    {$and: [
        {'location':{$geoWithin: {$centerSphere:[[ 72.50325, 23.01222 ], 50 / 6378.1]}}},
        {'location':{$geoWithin: {$centerSphere:[[ 72.7788, 23.8787 ], 50 / 6378.1]}}}
    ]}
)
```

returns no documents, since each of them is within own circle, but if you increase the distance e.g. to 500km:

```
db.collection.find(
    {$and: [
        {'location':{$geoWithin: {$centerSphere:[[ 72.50325, 23.01222 ], 500 / 6378.1]}}},
        {'location':{$geoWithin: {$centerSphere:[[ 72.7788, 23.8787 ], 500 / 6378.1]}}}
    ]}
)
```

it will return both documents.

They won't be sorted of course.

Comment: Thanks for your valuable answer. let me check.